# How to define a command that returns different commands based on a parameter

Tags: macros, hyperref

I would like to define a command `\mycommand` such that `\mycommand{X}` produces
`\Xfirst\Xsecond\label{Xlabel}`, where `\Xfirst` and `\Xsecond` are already defined commands.  Of course, `\mycommand{Y}` should produce `\Yfirst\Ysecond\label{Ylabel}`, and `\mycommand{Z}` should produce what you expected, and so on.  For instance, if I have

```
\newcommand{\Xfirst}{A}
\newcommand{\Xsecond}{xx}
\newcommand{\Yfirst}{B}
\newcommand{\Ysecond}{yy}
```

then using the command `\mycommand{X}` must be equivalent to writing `Axx\label{Xlabel}`, while writing `\mycommand{Y}` must be equivalent to writing `Byy\label{Ylabel}`.  I think I can do it with (a lot of) ifs.  Is there a more elegant form?  How?  Package `hyperref` should work well with the generated label.

An example following the suggestion of Ryan Reich (wrong link with hyperref).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\Xfirst}{A}
\newcommand{\Xsecond}{xx}
\newcommand{\Yfirst}{B}
\newcommand{\Ysecond}{yy}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
 \csname #1first\endcsname
 \csname #1second\endcsname
 \label{#1label}%
}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section}
    \mycommand{X}
    \pageref{Ylabel} % does not point to page 3
    \newpage
    Nothing.
    \newpage
    \mycommand{Y}
    \pageref{Xlabel}
\end{document}
```

Another attempt, using hypertarget and hyperlink.  It seems to work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\Xfirst}{A}
\newcommand{\Xsecond}{xx}
\newcommand{\Yfirst}{B}
\newcommand{\Ysecond}{yy}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
 \csname #1first\endcsname
 \csname #1second\endcsname
 \hypertarget{#1label}{}%
}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section}
    \label{section1}
    \mycommand{X}
    \hyperlink{Ylabel}{l1Y}
    \newpage
    \section{Another section}
    \label{section2}
    \hyperlink{Xlabel}{l2X}
    \hyperlink{Ylabel}{l2Y}
    \newpage
    \mycommand{Y}
    \hyperlink{Xlabel}{l3X}
    See Section 1 here~\ref{section1}.
    See Section 2 here~\ref{section2}.
\end{document}
```

A third attempt, with `\phantomsection`.  It also seems to work.  This is the better solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\Xfirst}{A}
\newcommand{\Xsecond}{xx}
\newcommand{\Yfirst}{B}
\newcommand{\Ysecond}{yy}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
 \csname #1first\endcsname
 \csname #1second\endcsname
 \phantomsection
 \label{#1label}{}%
}
\begin{document}
    \Huge
    \section{Section}
    \label{section1}
    \mycommand{X}
    X\pageref{Xlabel}
    Y\pageref{Ylabel}
    \newpage
    \section{Another section}
    \label{section2}
    X\pageref{Xlabel}
    Y\pageref{Ylabel}
    \newpage
    \mycommand{Y}
    X\pageref{Xlabel}
    Y\pageref{Ylabel}\par
    See Section 1 here~\ref{section1}.\par
    See Section 2 here~\ref{section2}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example with `\hypertarget` is much worse than my proposal with `\phantomsection`, since it does not automatically print either the section number or the page number.  What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I understood that you said that `\phanthomsection` would not work together with `\ref`, so I tried another solution using `hypertarget`.  That solution works, although it requieres some fine tunning yet.  Then, I decided to try `\phanthomsection` anyway, and it also works.  I agree in that the solution with `\phanthomsection` is much better, once you know it works.

Comment: What I meant was: if you use `\phantomsection` and then `\label`, the label will point to the phantom section rather than to the real previous section.  That's what you want if you're using `\pageref`, but if you use `\ref` on such a label, it will give you a link to the location of the phantom, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can generate a variable-named macro using the "environment" `\csname...\endcsname`.  For example, you could define:

```
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
 \csname #1first\endcsname
 \csname #1second\endcsname
 \label{#1label}%
}
```

which will produce exactly what you asked for.

**Edit:** Your example does display a bug, but not with my code.  The same thing happens if you replace the calls to `\mycommand` with direct `\label`s (of Xlabel and Ylabel).  This is because `hyperref` *itself* does not produce correct links with `\pageref`; this issue is discussed in [this `comp.text.tex` post](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-10/msg01898.html).

The basic reason for this is that, while `\label` saves the target reference's information in the .aux file, it does *not* produce a hypertarget at the place it is executed.  The target for `\pageref` is therefore exactly the same as the target for `\ref`, namely, the `\section` (or `equation`, or whatever) that produced it.  If you want to get around this, you must indicate to `hyperref` that you want the `\label` to refer not to the last `\section`, but to the *present location*.  This is done by inserting `\phantomsection` right before `\label`.  Thus, if this is your problem, you should use the following definition of `\mycommand`:

```
% Use this in case you *don't* install hyperref.
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
\newcommand\mycommand[1]{%
 \csname #1first\endcsname
 \csname #1second\endcsname
 \phantomsection
 \label{#1label}%
}
```

However, this will break uses of `\ref`, since they will now point to the location of the label rather than the labeled section.  I don't think you can have it both ways without hacking `\label`.

Comment: Text is ok, but `hyperref` links seem to be wrong. Is that possible?

Comment: You will have to be more specific about what you have and what is going wrong.  Please provide a minimal compilable document.

Comment: A was trying to add it here, but I could not.  Sorry.  I will add it in the main question.

Comment: That is the best place for it anyway.

Comment: `hyperlink` + `hypertarget` seems to work, as well as `\phanthomsection`.  See examples in the main question.